# Is brute-forcing the only way to crack WPA?

Tags: wifi, brute-force, wireless, wpa2

I don't know much about how WPA algorithms work internally. Is brute-forcing an AP the only way to crack WPA? (or to get associated with AP)

Another question is about [Reaver-WPS](https://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/), what if an access point doesn't support WPS, or is disabled? Will Reaver work on such AP

Comment: I don't have sources so I won't write an Answer, but no - you can go past WPA without brute-forcing it. It just that the math is complicated enough that running through the most common passwords first is probably faster for the intruder in many cases.

Comment: If WPS is disabled then the exploit against WPS won't work.  If you have questions about WPA I suggest you do some research on the algorithm.

Comment: Yes, WPA can be cracked without brute force. http://news.dice.com/2014/03/20/wpa2-security-cracked-without-brute-force/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPA can be used with different protocols. Using WPA-TKIP, there are alternative attacks than the common handshake-bruteforce, but those will not grant you access to the AP. These attacks focus on RC4 weaknesses (similar to WEP, but far less effective due to successful countermeasures).

I assume that you want to acces an AP. In this case, bruteforcing is the only possible way to crack WPA. You capture a handshake between client and accesspoint, and perform the challenge-response yourself with different passwords, until your result matches the one you captured.

This can be sped up by using rainbow-tables, although you will have to find a target using a popular SSID in order to have an existing rainbow table.

Thus, to protect against intruders, you should choose an uncommon SSID along with a fairly long and complex password.

And no, you can not attack WPS when WPS is disabled or not supported. There may be bugs preventing a user from disabling WPS, but i consider these APs WPS-enabled.

Comment: You might want to add a reference the "shoulder-surfing" (and similar) class of attacks to your answer: that usually the easiest way to grab a WAP/WEP password.

Comment: @Stephane a legitimate user will not type password everytime, however social engineering attacks always works

Comment: @MarkEvans That pretty much what I meant: brute-forcing the WAP key is usually not the easiest way in.